# Custom XPath Rule (created using "track breaches of XPath rule" template) not working in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

**I have created a custom rule in SonarQube using a XML template "Track breaches of an XPath rule".I am trying to run this rule on a project containing sample XML and after analysis I am not able to see any error. I have created my own quality profile and added the project and rule to the profile.I am running analysis through scannner and even on command prompt logs I am not able to see whether the rule is executed on project or not.**

The template of Track breaches of an XPath rule allows the definition of custom rules using XPath expressions.

Issues are created depending on the return value of the XPath expression. If the XPath expression returns:
• a single or list of AST nodes, then a line issue with the given message is created for each node 
• a boolean, then a file issue with the given message is created only if the boolean is true 
• anything else, no issue is created

**I have written XPath query according to the second condition of the template,it is returning a boolean value and that should return a file issue with a message if XPath is true.**

My sample XML-

```
<Eat>
<Fruit name="apple">
</Fruit>
</Eat>
```

The XPath which I have defined in My custom rule-
boolean(/Eat/Fruit/[@name = 'apple'])

**Thanks for help in advance!!!**

Comment: Try changing it to `/Eat/Fruit[@name='apple']`

Comment: Hi  ,thanks for help!! @AniketV .I tried your XPath rule but still I am facing same issue.